# JSch Fingerprint in Database

Tags: java, servlets, sftp, jsch

I have a Java Servlet application that uses JSch to SFTP documents from our SAN to the Servlet application and all works well.  However, it is running on Windows and to get this working we had to locate the "Host Key Fingerprint" created when we first connected to the SAN from the development machine and store this in a text file and then have the JSch point to this file as follows;

```
jsch.setKnownHosts("C:\\path\\to\\file\\fingerprintfilename.txt");
```

Is it possible to have the Host Key Fingerprint stored in a database?  Then I was hoping to use Hibernate to retrieve the Fingerprint for the setKnownHosts command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this before, but it should be possible. You can use the method `setKnownHosts(InputStream)` and you won't have to create temporary files from the data fetched from DB. Maybe you will have to use a charset in the `getBytes(Charset)` method to make it work properly. Or maybe you can store it directly as a BLOB and use the bytes.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("knownh hosts from the file".getBytes());
jsch.setKnownHosts(is);
```